# linking clickAction on a node in networkD3 to content preview in tab

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, shiny, networkd3

Is there an option to use `clickAction` from `forceNetwork` node to preview specific data for that node in panel beside the grid? I've managed to make `clickAction` call a hyperlink that leads to specific site, but I would like to change that, so that clicking on the node just presents some data to the right in the screen, not exiting the existing screen.

Here is the code with hyperlinks:

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

source =c(0,0,1,1,1,
      1,1,2,1,9,
      9,9,8,8,1,
      15,15,2,2,8)

target = c(1,2,3,4,5,
       6,7,8,9,10,
       11,12,13,14,15,
       16,17,18,19,20)

value = c(500,500,500,500,10,
      10,10,10,10,10,
      10,10,10,10,10,
      10,10,10,10,10)
MisLinks = data.frame(source,target,value)


name = c("spellsouls", "product","market", "flow", "progression",
     "guilds", "leaderbords","core mechanic", "audience", "live 
issues",
     "ux", "gd", "art", "personas", "TAM",
     "champions", "art","gd","videos","communication",
     "audience book")
group = c(1,2,2,3,3,
      3,3,3,3,3,
      4,4,4,4,4,
      3,4,4,4,4,
      4)
size = c(300,100,100,5,5,
     5,5,5,3,3,
     3,3,3,5,3,
     3,3,3,3,3,
     3)
hyperlink = c("https://confluence.hq.nordeus.com/x/SqwRAw", 
"http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", 
"http://google.com") #can't add more link in preview

MisNodes = data.frame(name, group, size, hyperlink)


ui = fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
           headerPanel(
             "Game perception: Knowledge base"),
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel("insights universe",
                      tags$head(tags$style("#force{height:100vh 
!important;}")),
                      forceNetworkOutput("force")),

             tabPanel("help", 
                      h1("User universe", align = "center"),
                      br(),
                      br(),
                      br(),
                      h4("This is a visual representation of our 
knowledge about Spellsouls", align = "center"),
                      h4("To read into more feedback we got for every 
specific feature of the game,", align = "center"),
                      h4("simply click on any node in the network", 
align = "center")
             )
           )

)





#Myclickaction = "window.open(d.hyperlink, '_blank')"

Myclickaction = "window.alert(d.hyperlink, '_blank')"
server = function(input,output) {

output$force = renderForceNetwork({
fn = forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
                  Source = "source", Target = "target", charge = 
-150,
                  legend = TRUE, opacityNoHover = 1, Nodesize = 
"size",
                  Value = "value", NodeID = "name", height = 1000, 
fontSize = 12,linkDistance = 50,
                  Group = "group", linkWidth = 2, clickAction = 
Myclickaction,
                  opacity = 0.9, colourScale =  
JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);"),
                  zoom=T)
fn$x$nodes$hyperlink <- hyperlink
fn

  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Desired outcome: link nodes from `forceNetwork`, to the new panel in UI that will show different content depending on the node clicked!

Comment: What do you mean by "to the new panel in UI"? You can modify the `clickAction` JavaScript to do something different, like show a box with whatever info you want in it... is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like `clickAction = "Shiny.onInputChange('id', d.description);"` to send a value of the clicked node back to a Shiny variable, which can then be used in a reactive element of the UI, such as...

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

links <- data.frame(source = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,9,9,9,8,8,1,15,15,2,2,8),
                       target = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),
                       value = c(500,500,500,500,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10))
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("spellsouls", "product","market", "flow", "progression",
                             "guilds", "leaderbords","core mechanic", "audience", 
                             "live issues","ux", "gd", "art", "personas", "TAM",
                             "champions", "art","gd","videos","communication",
                             "audience book"),
                    group = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4),
                    size = c(300,100,100,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3))
nodes$description <- paste("This is a description of", nodes$name)


ui = fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
               headerPanel("Game perception: Knowledge base"),
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("insights universe",
                          fluidRow(
                            column(10, forceNetworkOutput("force")),
                            column(1, textOutput("text"))
                          )
                        ),
                 tabPanel("help", 
                          h1("User universe", align = "center"),
                          br(),br(),br(),
                          h4("This is a visual representation of our 
                             knowledge about Spellsouls", align = "center"),
                          h4("To read into more feedback we got for every 
                             specific feature of the game,", align = "center"),
                          h4("simply click on any node in the network", 
                             align = "center")
                          )
                        )
               )

server = function(input,output) {
  output$force = renderForceNetwork({
    fn <- forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", 
                      Target = "target", charge = -150, legend = TRUE, 
                      opacityNoHover = 1, Nodesize = "size", Value = "value", 
                      NodeID = "name", height = 1000, fontSize = 12, 
                      linkDistance = 50, Group = "group", linkWidth = 2, 
                      clickAction = "Shiny.onInputChange('id', d.description);",
                      opacity = 0.9, zoom = T)
    fn$x$nodes$description <- nodes$description
    fn
  })

  output$text <- renderPrint({ input$id })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: related to d3 but not to this specific example, How to name the link ? Increase or decrease with an arrow pointer ? eg A --> B & on the connecting arrow "increase".